# Is the delay in the activation of the review buttons intentional?

Tags: discussion, review, usability

I was doing some reviews today and I noticed the `I'm done` and `Not sure` buttons are activated after a small delay and not as soon as the next question (or answer) loads.

I know this is a silly question but I really am curios: is this because the buttons simply need some time to load or is this a feature and intended so you won't be able to spammishly press the `Not sure` button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think because reviewing means that you actually have to *read* (or should at least *process*) the post that this is a technological way of enforcing that behavior for a higher-quality review; if the buttons were enabled immediately, you could just click random buttons and there would be no benefit.

It's like what you see on ToS/EULA agreements in software now, they require you to at least scroll to the end before the "I've read it" button appears (even though you haven't).

Comment: That's true and this is exactly why I suspected it might be intentional. But you cannot press the `I'm done` button without doing an action first (vote, comment, edit, flag), so this would only leave the `Not sure` button, which is simply a skip button and, as I understood, doesn't count towards the reviewing process

Comment: This is correct; it's intentional. Since reviews submitted too quickly would be eventually invalidated on the server side any way, we implemented a corresponding throttle on the client side.

Comment: @Emmett The throttling on server side for Skip doesn't seem to work, or is significantly shorter than the time it takes for the next review to load. I just wrote a bookmarklet that instantly disables the Skip button and it seems to be allowing me to skip immediately after load.