# Drop delay for "Skip" and increase it for "action" review buttons

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, usability

On some review items, I would like to skip them right away, but the skip button is disabled for some time.

Would it be possible not to disable the skip button?

- <sub>For example, when [reviewing questions to close](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), I'd like to skip some questions right away, and not wait for the skip button to become enabled.</sub>

Along with that, would it be possible to do opposite for "action" buttons? For actions, current delay feels like a compromise made with the sole purpose to allow for not too painful Skip.

If Skip button is not delayed at all, then longer "actions" delay could hopefully tame [review abuse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-abuse/info).

Comment: which review item are you talking about that the skip button is disabled?

Comment: **good idea** - it often takes me just a second or two to figure that post is out of my area of competence. ["_learn to love that Skip button_"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279/165773 "'if you can't be bothered to interpret an edit in the context of the post where it was made...'")

Comment: @psubsee2003 The skip button (for example) on this page : http://stackoverflow.com/review/close

Comment: @BЈовић thanks - reason I asked is I don't see the delay in the first posts or late answers queue (skip is enabled right away), so this must be unique to the close queue.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just tested _Close Votes_ and _Suggested Edits_ - skip is delayed there. Interesting, that it feels opposite for "action" buttons. I mean this delay feels too short for actions - that's probably a compromise made to allow for not too painful Skip

Comment: @gnat I see it now.  When you first bring up the queue (any queue), the skip button is enabled right away on the first post, but when moving to a new post after taking action (or skipping) the first, the skip button is disabled along with the other buttons.

Comment: @BЈовић how about re-phrasing this request into something like **drop delay for "Skip" and increase it for "action" review buttons**? Dropping will make Skip more comfortable, plus longer "actions" delay could hopefully tame [review abuse](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-abuse/info "what's this")

Comment: @gnat Sure. Thank you for the suggestion. That would be great. Will you, or should I? :)

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Is the delay in the activation of the review buttons intentional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147850/165773)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I like this idea.

Simply because currently, for me at least, it is a [race against the robo upvoters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561/165773) to get to the problematic posts and flag them before they get taken out of the queue. Faster skipping of ok posts (or ones I can't really judge) would really help.

Answer (score 11):

We will no longer delay the skip button after the next build.  This is exactly how review originally worked however it was missed in a refactor.

Comment: Could you also increase the duration for the other inputs by a factor of 1.5 perhaps?

Comment: Could we remove Status-completed, since only 1/2 this feature request was actually completed?

Answer (score 3):

I'd make a user script for this, but somehow I think the people that need an increased disabled cooldown the most are the ones that wouldn't install it. I still gave it a go (works because the throttling is entirely client side).

[image]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        skipfast
// @namespace   stackoverflow
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/review*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('.review-actions input[value="Skip"]').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Alternatively, you could add this as a bookmark and run it once when you go to the review page.

This is a good idea, not least because it makes sure the people with itchy trigger fingers have to wait **at least as long** as people who are actually reading the post. This would give serious reviewers a chance to actually get a say in the matter.