# A review audit tells you there's 5 close votes already

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, new-users, review-audits

In the First Posts review queue when having a test conducted on you on a question it shows you that the number of current close votes is 5.

> [image: test fail]

This is the result

> [image: test pass]

I passed this test but I'm guessing I shouldn't have been told that there were already 5 close votes on the question?

[Here's the review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1134002)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the review-audits tag @animuson but new-users over first-posts?

Comment: Man, I'm loving these edge cases.  It's developer schadenfreude.

Comment: @Ben: Check the [review tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review/info). ;) First posts are only ever posted by new users, so you're basically reviewing new users. It was actually the SE team who first started using that tag combination, as well.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an edge case @Charles. This is the third time it's happened to me. The problem is that I normally think ouch that's crap and the muscles take over the brain so I click "close" before I think about taking a screenshot.

Comment: @Ben, keep in mind that the audit posts are selected from the list of questions that were flagged and deleted by diamond mods.  Usually posts only appear in the queue when they're live and action needs to be taken.  Therefore, this is an edge case: normally we want to know there are close votes, and this time, not so much.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, the audit queues are taking much longer to wring out than I would have expected.  Take that, you scheduling determinists.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm not surprised.  I expect that they wanted to make sure that it's an adequate test first and didn't worry about making it perfect during the first iteration.

Comment: @RobertHarvey now that it's clear that doing audits right will take quite a lot of time, the question is rather why SE team doesn't try cheaper / quicker ways to at least "lower the tension"? I mean stuff like [tuning action buttons timeouts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157073/165773 "suggested here"), [short-lived locks for suggestions under review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits/155619#comment447240_155619 "'...would probably work and be rather cheap'"), stuff like that

Comment: @gnat: I don't really get the skip delay; it sounds like micro-management to me. Locks are difficult to get right on web pages.  TBH I found the Review dialog counterintuitive initially; for some reason it took me awhile to get used to it, but I like it now.  It works especially well on the smaller sites.

Comment: @RobertHarvey skip is delayed probably because it appeared simplest to implement back then, like _let's do this for all the buttons_. For a new, untested feature that would be somewhat reasonable approach; it jut took some time to find out that timing out skip and action buttons same way is like running with hands tied behind your back

Comment: Its already easy to tell if a review is a test or not when all you have to do to trigger a pass is click the comment or flag links before you might otherwise upvote or skip. Really the test completion event should fire on clicking the "I'm Done" button to be sure the user was actually going to commit to that action

Comment: Isn't it amazing that everyone finding quirks in the tests are _actually paying attention to what they're doing to begin with?_ :)

Comment: @TimPost well if test purpose is _just_ to make user pay attention then I have a perfect test design for that. Just break a randomly picked review and display a (randomly choosen) either of _"Congratulations!"_ or _"STOP!"_ messages. Simple and bulletproof isn't it? one would just have to edit [review-audits tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info) and drop that crap about "honing skills" from there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Audits will not show you any indication of previous close votes.  This was fixed a few weeks ago and seems to be working well.

Comment: Looks broken again; I just got an audit in the Close Votes queue that had `[closed]` in the title of the question.