# "This is just a test" - leaked

Tags: bug, review-audits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A test tells you there’s 5 close votes already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157768/a-test-tells-you-theres-5-close-votes-already)

I notice that sometimes there are audit tests in the review queues (First Posts).

Sometimes, I believe I have seen this 3 times now, there will be 5 close votes visible. Whenever it shows 5 close votes, it leaks the fact that it is a test.

At the bottom of the post, you see `share | edit | close(5) | flag`. If there are 5 close votes, it would already be closed and would not appear in the review queue... unless it is a test!.

Therefore, in these cases, it should never display 5 close votes, or else it tips the reviewer that they are being tested.