# An audit shows you that the question is already closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, new-users, review-audits

*This may be related to my question [A review audit tells you there's 5 close votes already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157768/a-review-audit-tells-you-theres-5-close-votes-already).*

I just failed an audit in the First Posts review queue. The question clearly stated that it was closed (Possible Duplicate link and everything) so I clicked <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>. As the closed link was at the top of the question this seemed to be a reasonable course of action (more fool me).

I don't have a pre-audit screenshot as I wasn't expecting to need one. It basically looked exactly the same as the below apart from the score, which was displayed as 0.

> [image: Aarrrgghh]

[Here's the review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1332144)

Comment: Hmm...  The post was apparently chosen because it was deleted by the community shortly after it was closed, so the bug is *the presence of the "Possible Duplicate" banner* on a First-Post Review, as you wouldn't have known that the post was closed otherwise.

Comment: The pre-audit screenshot would have shown zero votes, with no mention of [closed] in the title.  The bug with the close votes being exposed has apparently been fixed already.

Comment: Yes @Robert, it might be simpler to exclude questions closed as duplicates entirely from review audits to stop this from happening (though I didn't see the 5 close votes so it looks like that got fixed!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posts that were closed *as duplicates* are now never chosen for audits. Good catch.

Comment: Please have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168033/.