# Security Audit: First post, what was the proper reaction?

Tags: support, bug, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

See https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1544210.

The question was already migrated to meta, so I clicked "no action needed", but got "review audit failed".

So what was the **proper vote** is this case?

<sup>I have the feeling that the audit system is deeply messed up. A day before I had a failed audit b/c I voted to close [nodejs server against DOS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14755707/), which is closed by now.</sup>

Comment: @nhahtdh: that's not there in 'first posts'

Comment: @Manishearth: Nah, I don't remember what are the choice there. I only review 2 posts in total for the First Post queue (new review system).

Comment: *I don't know how to tag* is way to broad. It should be closed as *Not a real question*.

Comment: I guess this is related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163747/an-audit-shows-you-that-the-question-is-already-closed, looks like migrated questions should be excluded as well as dupes. Though dupes could now be included again as the banner isn't part of the question (though I think it's a little unfair to include them at all).

Comment: @juergend - on **Meta** possibly, but on SO itself the question is simply Off Topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have (a) downvoted and/or (b) flagged (or close voted if you have the rep). Of course, you had no reason to, since it was already migrated.

I guess it's a bug that migrated questions display that they are migrated when they turn up in an audit. IIRC, almost all audits are shown in the state they were *before* deletion/closing/migration. Or, at least, they *should* show that.

Comment: This can be turned into a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have used one of this options, but they felt out of place. I should have known that it was an audit. :)