# Eeeeek! Close review audit shows you that the question is already on hold

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close, review-audits

I just got [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2416567) for close votes. But it says me that the question is already on hold.

> [image]

I realized that this it an audit. And I clicked on <kbd>Close</kbd>. Hurrah! I passed an audit without any efforts!

> [image]

Can we fix this? Please.

<sub>Note: We may say that this it a duplicate to this question: [An audit shows you that the question is already closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163747/187824). But that question is for *First Posts* while this question is for *Close vote*.</sub>

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an EEEEK!, in quite the same way as EEEEK! You moved my cheese! does.

Comment: Agree with @Robert here, at most it's "Ek". Nothing is broekn. :)

Comment: I think that is the whole point of the review audit. *All* of the questions shown for review audit are *shown* as closed. If the close looks "wrong", vote leave open and the fake close disappears...

Comment: @talonmies nope. "leave open" means dispute existing flags, it's meaningless if the question is already closed plus it will result in failing the audit.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I review a lot of close votes on [SO]. Every audit I have had (probably at least 20) looks like this. It seems to be by design.

Comment: Yes @Sha Exact duplicate. Thanks.