# Getting what appear to be reopen audits in close vote queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, closed-questions, review-audits

I just noticed this:

[image: closed audit]

Really? A closed question is in the close vote queue? Not likely.

It seems that the action to take on these is to click leave open - which passes the audit. I got [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2500300) before this and clicked close and failed the audit.

Could this be fixed? Please?

Comment: Him. The other question is marked "status-completed"...

Comment: @Seth Hadn't noticed that, only 13 hours ago. If it's still happening, probably want to report it on [his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188466). He'll reopen this if need be.

Comment: @animuson Okay.. I don't review on [so] though so someone else will need to test it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently fixed the audit with a known *bad* question, where the post is now disguised as a good one - previously it was just left as is.

**Update**

The reopen and close review queues shared the same logic for creating review audits. This has been fixed and will be rolling out shortly.

Comment: Soo... shouldn't it not indicate it's closed? This isn't the reopen queue.

Comment: [This also please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186757/187824)