# Broaden the qualifications for a First Post or a Late Answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, late-answers

From a reviewer standpoint, as I understand it, a post qualifies as a *First Post* if it is the first question or answer ever posted by a user, and a *Late Answer* is similarly a first post, but also applied to a long-lived question.  If this is true, from my experience reviewing questions and answers in the primary questions queue (outside of the review queue), **I think the *First Post* and *Late Answer* qualifications are too tight and should be broadened.**

In my time editing, I have encountered many *Second and Subsequent Posts* requiring review due to consistently poor grammar by Users who

1. are fairly new, but have gained reputation arbitrarily
2. are revisiting after several months, having asked one random question long ago, which disqualifies them as a First User even though they really do need to be reviewed
3. are enthusiastic new users who post several consecutive questions

Posts from these types of users (and others) slip through the existing review cracks when in actuality, they should qualify for review in the same classification as *First Posts* and *Late Answers*, and it should not require attentive users babysitting the primary question lists to spot them.

**I would suggest *any* or *all* of the following alterations:**

1. Based on my definition of *Late Answer*, merge it with *First Post*, since it's just a subset of *First Post*

   - unless my definitions are incorrect; please correct any wrong-headedness in the comments.
   - note you'll need to merge the review badge counts of all users
2. Rename *First Post* to *Inexperienced Post*.
3. Flag any post (question or answer) as an *Inexperienced Post* if the user hits **any** of the following ordered qualifications *(note: **italicized bold values** were selected arbitrarily)*:

   1. had at least 1 post sitting in the review queue within the last ***24*** hours
   2. registered less than ***1*** month ago (optional: on all SE sites)
   3. has less than ***50*** reputation

      - must not be single-sourced reputation (I registered my e-mail address; +50!)
      - preferably determined using only post-based reputation
      - optionally may be total post-based reputation across all SE sites
   4. has less than ***5*** posts total
   5. whatever other rules qualify a *Late Answer* / *First Post*

Implementing some of these may also solve the superficial problems of

1. having hungry review queues
2. reviewing experienced users of other SE sites, which is probably still necessary due to the variation of FAQ requirements between sites (I know I've needed review on other SE sites).

Comment: Also, new users who post several questions (or answers!) before their First Post ever really gets reviewed/edited/commented on. Basically anything they've posted before getting feedback would presumably be equivalent to a "first post"

Comment: Late answers usually have lots of first posts in them, yes, but they are not technically related. A late answer is simply that: an answer that comes in a very long time after a question was asked. The coincidence is simply that new users find these questions on google and try to respond to them (often poorly).

Comment: So, my initial qualification here for late answers being "those which are late AND from new users" is incorrect, then?  A "Late Answer" would then be one which is both late and from ANY user?  If so, then my call to merge is invalid and I would remove it once this is confirmed.

Comment: Actually, thats simply what I thought it was. I checked the wording to confirm, and it does say it's late AND new. If that's the case then I would have to agree with pretty much all of your post.

Comment: Late AND new; that's what I thought, which means it is defined (at least textually) as a subset.  Then my initial suggestion stays for now.

Comment: @Jim - I added "more than 0 not-yet-reviewed posts for user" to cover your suggestion.

Comment: As it is now, I believe "new users" for the late answer queue is reputation based, while first post is explicitly one post per user, so they are not currently subsets. But they would be using your suggested system, so it makes sense to merge them in that case.

Comment: I also like to have those predefined comments on the First Post review.

Comment: @Jim - I changed it to "had at least 1 post sitting in the review queue within the last 24 hours", but that should cover your item.  Granted, that leaves the potential for a severely active new user to be perpetually under review, but I doubt it'll be like that, and the 24 value is an arbitrary malleable one taken from the aether.

Answer (score 5):

Late Answer is not a subset of First Post. A user with one or more posts and a rep of 1-10 (either because they just joined and are asking many questions in a row, or because their questions have been downvoted) who asks a question or answers a recent question will not be reviewed. But if they answer a really old question they will be.

More importantly, I review these differently. In Late Answers I am mainly looking for self promotion and "I have this too" NaA. I am therefore mainly thinking "flag". In First Posts, I am mainly thinking "edit". You can gain more insight into review mindset at [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/147247)

I would prefer the two queues stayed separate. I have no objection to a broader definition of "first post" since I think second and third posts are likely to also need help.

Comment: As noted, I suggested "any or all of the following alterations", which means suggestion item #1 (combination of First Post and Last Answer) can be skipped.  If the ranges listed in suggested item #3 can still apply to a Late Answer to increase the number of qualifying posts, then they should still be applied.