# De-emphasize the review count # if the count is 0, or emphasize queues with positive count

Tags: feature-request, review

I know I am not the only user who refreshes the review queues summary screen hunting for items to review, and occasionally when we finally don't see 0, it's possible to refresh or click away from the page out of habit, then come back and the hungry masses have already consumed the reviews.

The review queues do sort to the top when there are reviews available, but positions do not change if suddenly all queues gain values, which does happen often.

I've mentioned before ways to pad the queues by [extending qualifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171512/what-qualifies-a-post-as-a-first-post-or-a-late-answer-and-should-these-qualifi), but the following is a simple user interface recommendation:

Remove the bold from a review queue's number when the value is zero, or maintain the bold for aesthetics, but change the number color to non-black for queues with values greater than zero.  This allows the queue to stand out from other, viable queues that have a 0 count.  I'd alternately suggest graying them out, but that has another meaning (it's used when you can no longer review for the day), so the recommendation is to instead emphasize those queues greater than 0 which can be processed by the user.

In addition to queues with positive values bubbling to the top, place a horizontal rule or other divider between any viable queue (positive value) and non-viable queues (zero value, grayed-out) to emphasize the importance.

Comment: Queues with items are placed above queues without items you know..

Comment: Queue positioning doesn't change if it's the first queue that shows a gain.  Put a horizontal rule between queues with positive and negative values.

Comment: Negative values? Like, negative reviews remaining?

Comment: Mis-typed.  Positive and ZERO values.  Wiseguy.  :)

Comment: It's a set of review queues.Why not just take an extra second to read them correctly?