# Have first posts include more than just the first post

Tags: discussion, review, new-users

So I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610173/how-far-does-the-concept-of-snowden-taking-refuge-in-nations-seem-a-direct-atta) (which is, to say the least, way off topic). [The user who posted it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2575535/rajdeep-kalsi) has 1 reputation with no questions or answers, so I assume one or more of his/her questions has already been deleted. I have checked the First Post review history and that question **did not** show up there.

Now I'm not sure whether this is a rare occurrence or not (I can't exactly query for deleted posts (or can I?)). If you **know** this to be a rare occurrence, feel free to point this out.

Probably more importantly, there's of course also the extremely low quality posts we've come to accept as a part of StackOverflow (not something we want, but most of us probably accept that it's not really something we can easily get rid of, without a cost). Whether these are mainly posted by users I am to describe below I'm not really sure of either.

So basically:
Is there a problem? (Yes, at least for the latter case) Will the below fix it?

I propose we review what users' posts constitutes a "first post". Possible suggestions:

1. At least include users that don't have any non-deleted posts
2. Include users that don't have upvoted questions / answers
3. Generalize to all users with less than 10 reputation
4. Include answers / questions of users that have only posted questions / answers
5. Have it be dependent on passing x previous First Post reviews
6. Users get reintegrated into the review system after x or x% of posts flagged (within the last x days?), regardless of reputation
7. Any other suggestions?

The idea with these suggestions, as with first posts, is (I assume) to only have (self-)selected individuals check to see if they are of sufficient quality to reach the public and also to teach the offending users in the process.

We may have to try this out for a while, in case there are way too many of these posts and not enough reviewers.

If the problem is that too many very low quality questions are getting through the First Post review largely unaltered, that's a different problem we need to look at.

**PS:**

Keep in mind that, even if most of the low quality posts are by users that don't fall into these categories, over time, it could help in the sense that users will go through multiple reviews which will iron out minor problems in their posts, thus they should be decent at posting by the time they are no longer getting reviewed (or banned before then).

Comment: +1.  Anybody who has no active (undeleted) posts for sure should go in the queue; 2 is also a good idea, I think, as long as the upvotes do come for reasonable questions (and I think perhaps encouraging reviewers to upvote questions in the review queue more than they do now would be a good thing, especially if we add a few more first review looks like in the other question).

Comment: @apaul34208 Not really, that post seems to focus more on the queue itself, not what should go to the queue (which is what my post focuses on).

Comment: @Dukeling sorry it just reminded me of one of the answers there - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184036/217863 which refers to this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171512/broaden-the-qualifications-for-a-first-post-or-a-late-answer

Comment: The suggestions are somewhat distinct. Should this be closed as a duplicate in this case? Should this maybe be posted as an answer to that post, or an edit (so all the suggestions are in one place)? And everyone's voting as a dup of the wrong question...

Comment: It's Meta, dups work differently here ... :)